# Close modal window and clean hash in the same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hash

I load content into a div via ajax. This changes the website hash to #WhateverYouClickedOn, that's fine. I want to clean the hash once the user clicks the x button that closes this modal window. **How could i do that?**

**This is my code**

**Ajax call**

```
function getPage() {
    return window.location.hash.replace(/^#/, '');
}

function updatePage(page, html) {

    var navItems = [
        'products',
        'about',
        'storelocator',
        'media',
        'faq',
        'contact'
    ];
$('.overlay').trigger('show');
    // Remove the arrow from the previously selected item
    if (navItems.indexOf(page) != -1) {
        $(".w-container .w-nav-menu a").removeClass("active");
    }

    $("#" + page + "-link").addClass("active");

    $('.content')
        .hide()
        .html(html)
        .fadeIn();
}

function retrieveContent() {
     $('.overlay').trigger('show');
    var page = getPage();

if (!page) {   
        return;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./load.php",
        data: 'page='+page,
        dataType: "html",

        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#canvasloader-container.wrapper').show();
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#canvasloader-container.wrapper').hide();
        },                
        success: function(msg){
            if (msg) {
                updatePage(page, msg);
            }
        }
    });
}

$(function() {
    retrieveContent();

    window.onhashchange = retrieveContent;
});
```

**Overlay / Modal window**

```
(function($) { 
  $.fn.overlay = function() {
    overlay = $('.overlay');

    overlay.ready(function() {
      overlay.on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd', function(e) {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('shown')) return $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
      });

      overlay.on('show', function() {
        $(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
        $(this).addClass('shown');

        return true;
      });
     overlay.on('hide', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('shown');
        $(".content").html("")
        return true;

      });
     overlay.on('hide', function() {
       $(".w-container .w-nav-menu a").removeClass('active'); // Remove the active class when overlay is off
       $(".content").html("")
       return true;

     });


      $('a[data-overlay-trigger=""]').on('click', function() {
        overlay.trigger('show');
      });

      $('a[data-overlay-trigger]:not([data-overlay-trigger=""])').on('click', function() {
        $('.overlay.' + $(this).attr('data-overlay-trigger')).trigger('show');
      });
    })
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Have you tried `location.hash = "";`?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan this will cause a jerk on page scroll, maybe reload the page

Comment: this might be useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: @SidVishnoi It won't reload the page, as hash changes do not cause reloads (the whole point of using `onhashchange` for SPAs). It might cause the page to jump to the top, but the OP didn't say anything about what the desired effect was.

Comment: it doesn't redirect (my bad) but does cause a jump to jump

Comment: @Josef : on close: 
`history.replaceState(null, "", window.location.pathname)`

Comment: @SidVishnoi That solved the problem!